# Apollo InMemoryCache silently drops data of fragments defined on root query

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client

When such query is requested (assuming it is correct for my graphql server):

```
fragment B on root_query {
    foo {
        id
    }
}

query A {
    ...B
}
```

The data that comes from the server contains `foo` field, but after it comes through apollo's `InMemoryCache` and i receive it from `ApolloClient.query()` or `useQuery()` said field is missing.

`foo` that comes from server has correct `__typename` and `id`.

I've expected to see `fragment B` contents in `result.data`, but they are missing and there is no errors or warnings.

If I inline the fragment to query everything works fine.

Comment: Could you please create a reproduction for that and open an issue over at GitHub?

Comment: Yeah I'll do it right now. Just left it here with the answer for the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

When root query has custom name in server schema (like `root_query`) it has to be defined in cache settings like that:

```
new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
        typePolicies: {
            query_root: { queryType: true }
        }
    })
    // Remaining options...
})
```

Otherwise apollo assumes that fragment was used incorrectly and apparently silently discards the data.